# How can I insert rows in PANDA data in Python?

Tags: pandas

How can I insert rows in PANDA data in Python?
I am currently loading the data from a query
example `data = pd.read_sql_query (query, con)`
the data has the following structure:

```
timestamp data1 data2
1515581720 12 23
1515581721 23 34
1515581723 45 34
1515581724 45 23
```

I would like to know, if it is possible to insert a new row on the
information obtained from mysql in dataframe of the Panda library.
In the previous case the registration "1515581722" is missing,

should be:

```
timestamp data1 data2
1515581720 12 23
1515581721 23 34
***1515581722 NULL NULL***
1515581723 45 34
1515581724 45 23
```

Stay tuned to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your timestamps should be a range, you can do

```
timestamps = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(1515581720, 1515581724)), columns=['timestamp'])
data = pd.merge(timestamps, data, how='left', on='timestamp')
```

The first line creates a new dataframe with all timestamps in the given range

```
   timestamp
0  1515581720
1  1515581721
2  1515581722
3  1515581723
4  1515581724
```

and the second line merges this new dataframe to your original data with `NaN` where there is no match:

```
   timestamp  data1   data2
0  1515581720   12    23
1  1515581721   23    34
2  1515581722   NaN   NaN
3  1515581723   45    34
4  1515581724   45    23
```

Comment: Before your code did I upload the data? data = pd.read_sql_query (query, con)

Comment: yes you have to run data = pd.read_sql_query (query, con) before

Comment: When executing the code gives error

TypeError: __init __ () got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

Answer (score 0):

There is another way

```
df.set_index('timestamp').reindex(range(df.timestamp.min(),df.timestamp.max()+1)).reset_index()
Out[297]: 
    timestamp  data1  data2
0  1515581720   12.0   23.0
1  1515581721   23.0   34.0
2  1515581722    NaN    NaN
3  1515581723   45.0   34.0
4  1515581724   45.0   23.0
```